# Public personal ideas: using contributions from other people

Tags: soft-question

Let's say I'm thinking about an unsolved mathematical problem for a hobby and I draw some conclusions of my own. I'd like to make these ideas public, allow anyone to use them absolutely freely (even without mentioning me) and maintain these ideas on my blog/notes website.

Now let's say a reader leaves a comment and contributes with something extra, advancing the quest to solving the unsolved mathematical problem. Maybe he/she improved an idea I already posted. I want to then continue with my hobby free to use ideas that my readers are posting, meaning, make it clear that I don't owe them anything as I use their ideas, it is therefore their responsibility if they choose to post something under this condition. I don't want to get to be in a situation where someone demands something from me because 'they came up with it'. Once some mathematical result R is communicated from person A to person B, B cannot simply "undo" this exchange even if he wants to. He cannot simply pretend he "doesn't know" R.

How could I approach this? Is it enough to mention my conditions on my website? Would I be legally bound to anything in such a situation or is this actually a non-problem and I'm overthinking it?

(I'm not sure what the proper place to ask this is, I've also [posted it on the 'law' stackexchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/55642/personal-ideas-website-using-contributions-from-readers-freely).)

Comment: I think that in some ways you are over-thinking it... but, on another hand, the notion of "possession" of ideas is curiously widespread... _and_ just by explaining your wishes on a website may or may not obligate users of the site to anything... depending on your jurisdiction and theirs. I myself have thought about such things for some years, and/but I'll wait to see what younger people have to say (since my pre-internet experience seems to have made me "more radical" than others... or... something...)

Comment: As far as I'm concerned it's not really a question of legality but rather of acceptable academic practice, the interpretation of which varies greatly among individual people. The most important thing is always to communicate clearly.

Comment: While it is somewhat too optimistic to expect every mathematician to be sane, demanding something from a non-profit user because of a comment one left on a website is truly insane.

Comment: Depends on the situation. Whenever this happens to you you can update the question with the concrete circumstances.  Then maybe you can get a more concrete advice.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, legal issues exist too, e.g. when the mathematics shows up in a patent dispute: https://www.greyb.com/mathematical-formula-claim-patent-eligible/

Comment: You mention crossposting to LawSE, but maybe also [AcademiaSE](http://academia.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: As long as you do not claim any exclusive rights on the final solution, nobody will be in a position to demand anything from you though some people may still try (you cannot overestimate the desire of people to say "It was I, who..."). However, if you officially publish the result, the general politeness demands that you don't just do it under your own name without mentioning other contributors. You don't owe them anything only as long as you do not try to convert the abstract idea into a tangible personal benefit. I do not know what the law has to say, but that is what my common sense says.

Comment: If you are really serious about this, my advice would be to hire a lawyer, rather than depending on the opinions of random people on websites (like me).

Comment: This isn't a question of owing, this is a question of integrity. When you sign a paper, you are implicitly saying that everything in the paper is your own contribution (shared between the authors if there are multiple). Whether you need to acknowledge something or not is of course a judgment call dependent on what exactly what was given to you, how much it helped, etc. But you cannot just get away with a disclaimer on your website, because you cannot excuse yourself from lying to your readers. And law is completely irrelevant here, neither copyright nor patents apply.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi I intend to give appropriate credits along the way, even though it might become cumbersome. I do not intend to claim something to be my own when it is not, nor make money out of this. What I'm mostly concerned about is not getting into senseless debates over who said what when, with users claiming something unreasonable. I'm just wondering how big is the risk for that to happen. If some significant result comes out of my website, I do not want to be responsible with more than saying, if asked, "I said this, the community said the rest, credits are there".

Comment: The more I think about this the more I get the feeling I'm better off keeping this hobby private, it's just simpler :) Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Well that's already how it works. People write "The author thanks XXX for helpful discussions and comments" in their acknowledgments sections all the time. But your question sounded like you didn't even want to have to write that.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi Yes I see your point, but it's one thing to write a _finalized_ research article on your own or with a limited group of people you can get along with and completely another to invite everybody to the party. I do not want the responsibility of crediting everybody with what they say or worse dealing with unreasonable demands, hence this detail missing from the question: no expectations should be baseline. I don't know it seems fishy.

Comment: It is normal and expected to credit someone (a mere sentence in the acknowledgement section generally suffices) who helped you in a meaningful way to complete the article through their comments or suggestions. You have nothing to lose by doing this, so I really do not understand your reluctance. What are you afraid of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When it comes to legal rights, I think a disclaimer might suffice, though IANAL and you maybe should consult one.

When it comes to giving proper attribution and credit for ideas, I think this is not (or not only) something that an author owes to a specific originator of the ideas, but rather (or also) something an author owes to the community at large.  In particular, if I read your blog and make significant use of your original ideas to write a paper, and don't cite (or otherwise acknowledge) your blog, I have committed plagiarism whether you care or not.  Similarly, if I leave an important comment and you use it to write a paper, you are obliged to cite or acknowledge the comment whether I care or not.  (Note this obligation persists even if I remain completely anonymous, even untraceably so!)  This is because you have a duty to your readers to make as clear as possible the history of the ideas in your paper, in addition to anything you might "owe" me as originator of those ideas.

(There has been one situation where knowing that a particular theorem in a paper was due to an anonymous referee and not the author arguably led me to pursuing the right ideas in my own research.)